# How to add Logo (watermark) to Videos using ffmpeg - Clipbucket script

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

How to add Logo (watermark) to Videos using ffmpeg - Clipbucket script

The files are `ffmpeg.class.php` and `conversion.class.php` of the script that does the processing - conversion. where can I add some code to allow this watermark in the videos I upload to my site?

https://github.com/arslancb/clipbucket/tree/master/upload/includes/classes/conversion

Thanks in advance,
Spiro

Comment: Dont just provide an external link to your source code. Why do you think users will take efforts to click link and go through entire of your code. Instead spend some time providing properly formatted snippets of your code, provide what are you trying to achieve, what have you tried so far and what kind of problem your are stuck with.

Comment: problem is I don't have php knowledge so i am really asking if someone can give me some code to try ?